# Server.Transfer is failing for Facebook app

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have a facebook app which I'm trying to execute a Server.Transfer on.
On my dev box everything works fine but on our server, we get an error:

> Error executing child request for TestPage.aspx.
>      at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
>      at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
>      at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)
>      at Games_Facebook_MasterPage.OnConnected(JsonObject user)

I'm not sure if this is a server setting issue or something to do with it being a Facebook app.

Suggestions?

Comment: And what does the code look like?

Comment: Server.Transfer("TestPage.aspx");

Comment: Do you mean `Server.Transfer("~/TestPage.aspx");` ?

Comment: No it's in the same location as the current page. I did try it as you wrote as well but no change. Keep in mind this does work on my dev box but not on the server

Comment: Found the issue. On the server, TestPage had an error and instead of being displayed, Transfer swallowed the error and displayed its own.

Comment: Awesome that your found your problem. You should post an answer in case someone else has this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. TestPage.aspx was throwing an exception in the Page_Load and Server.Transfer was swallowing the exception and throwing its own. Because of this, it seemed like Server.Transfer was failing but in reality it was TestPage.aspx